# Honda Civic, severe bouncing and shaking on highway when accelerating plus noise

Tags: honda, noise, civic, vibration

2009 Honda Civic. here is the story, 2 months ago i was driving on a curve and I did not notice some black ice, I lost control and the car spun once then went over the curb. The inner plastic lining over the tire got damaged but that was about it, ever since then i Immediately noticed a lot of bouncing and vibration whenever i go over 60 on the highway, around 75 I get the most intense bouncing and there is also a noise whenever i have my foot on the pedal at that speed, I am not sure how to describe the sound but it is sort of like something is bumping about 4-5 times per second.

I have taken my vehicle immediately to a repair shop, told them about the problem, paid $70 just for them to inspect it and they told me everything is fine. I took my vehicle again to a tire shop, inspected the tires and the wheels and they said nothing was wrong and they re-balanced the wheels, the problem didn't go away. I took it to another shop and he told me the axle is bad, I was ready to replace the axle but decided to check another mechanic just in case, he told me the axle is fine and he sees nothing wrong. I am not car savvy so I don't know what to do anymore.

The car used to drive very smoothly before the accident, but now it keeps shaking all over the place, i even keep feeling that the vehicle starts to lose control in direction whenever i go over bumpy roads, I never lose control but for a fraction of a second it feels like the car is about to start sliding.

I would like to take it to the dealership but I am concerned about the cost of the inspection and all that. will they check for free or do I have to pay for them to check? I am already planning to have oil change with them anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Any kind of diagnostic you ask them to do will cost money. There is usually a fee of at least an hour labor at whatever the going rate is for your area. If it takes them longer than that to diagnose the issue, they'll charge more.

Comment: The bouncing could be caused by bent suspension parts (control arms?)

Comment: Did any of the places, that supposedly diagnosed it, actually drive the vehicle at highway speed? If not, I would take it back and demand they do, since you payed them to diagnose a problem that only occurs at those speeds.

Answer (score 1):

Most professionals won't do it for free, and for the safety of yourself and everyone else on the road I would stay away from any free diagnosis for this symptom.  Correct me if Im wrong, but Im guessing the one who told you it was an axle may have been the only one actually drove it at 75 mph.

I suspect that the inner cv joint on the side that had the curb damage is causing the noise on acceleration.  It also sounds like either an alignment and/or strut problem if you have the feeling of losing control over bumps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the CV joint or the engine mount. I'd probably have the CV joint looked at professionally first.